# Is there a way to stream live video from an iPad to an Apple TV?

Tags: ipad, video, appletv, streaming, airplay

AirPlay is a great feature for stream audio/video to iOS devices, but can you stream live video? For example, instead of recording the video and then streaming it, can you just stream on the fly? I want to shoot video with an iPad and stream it to an Apple TV on the same network.

Mirroring the default camera app essentially works for just video, but since audio is not being capture, there is no audio sent to the Apple TV. What are my options?

Comment: Are you looking for a software recommendation about what app to run on the iPad?

Comment: I'm looking for a solution to the problem. An app would be good. If there is a way to do this natively using AirPlay, that would be better. I haven't found any apps that can do this.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it yet but according to these articles Ustream will enable you to do it:

- [Ustream Launches iPad-Optimized iOS App, Adds Apple AirPlay Support](http://www.scribbal.com/2011/07/ustream-launches-ipad-optimized-ios-app-adds-apple-airplay-support/)
- [UStream for iPad](http://www.ustream.tv/everywhere/ipad)

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll see if this works. It sounds like it might only have airplay for streaming other peoples videos, but hopefully it can stream to the Apple TV as it records.